# How do I proxy_pass to a unix socket in a server location other than root?

Tags: sockets, nginx, proxypass

I can proxy_pass using the root location like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuser/app/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

And if I `curl mysite.com` I see the expected JSON output.

But how can I make this available at `curl mysite.com/myapi/`? If I use `location /myapi/` or `location /myapi` it doesn't work. I have also tried sticking an `alias /;` in there but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Both the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements require a trailing `/`.